# Given $x =(x_1,x_2,x_3)T$ and $y =(y_1,y_2,y_3)T$ determine which of the following are inner products for$ R3×1$:

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\bf{x}$ $= (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ and $\bf{y}$ $= (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T$ determine which of the following are inner products for $R^{3 \times 1}$:

a) $<\bar x, \bar y> = x_1y_1 + x_3y_3$

b) $<\bar x, \bar y> =2x_1y_1 +x_2y_2 + 4x_3y_3$

Now, I know the definition of a general inner product is the following:

(i) $<\bar x, \bar x>$ is real with $<\bar x, \bar x> \ \ge 0$, and $= 0$ iff $\bar x = \bar 0$.

(ii) $<\bar x, \alpha \bar y> = \alpha<\bar x, \bar y>$ for all scalars.

(iii) $<\bar x, \bar y + \bar z> = <\bar x, \bar y> + <\bar x, \bar z>$

(iv) $<\bar x, \bar y>  = <\bar x, \bar y>$ (at least for real spaces).

According to my solution manual, a) is not an inner product for $R^{3 \times 1}$ because it fails the first condition. I'm not seeing how this is true.

Furthermore, my solution manual says b) $\textit{is}$ an inner product for $R^{3 \times 1}$. Again, not seeing this.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the matrix of such bilinear (hopefully) products? Do you know the matrix must be, in this real case, positive definite (and symmetric to begin with, of course)? And this is an iff .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), it fails the first condition, because for instance $\langle(0,1,0),(0,1,0)\rangle=0$.

For part (b), I agree with your solution manuel that it is an inner product. Which property are you having difficulties with?